# Javascript filereader open hard-coded filename with --allow-file-access-from-files

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have some javascript which loads a file based on user input:

```
function openFile(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    const result = reader.result.split("base64,")[1];
    // use result
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

I want to hard-code the file name. If I were *writing* to file, I would try something like

```
function openFile2(filename) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    const result = reader.result.split("base64,")[1];
    // use result
  };
  var file = new File([""], filename) // create a new file object for writing (not actually desired)
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

But here I am *reading*, so I want an existing file, not a new one. I've found several similar questions in which the answers assert that **this is not possible** for security reasons:

- [How to read local files using HTML 5 FileReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849745/how-to-read-local-files-using-html-5-filereader)
- [How to read file in Java Script line by line from hardcoded path and name of the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994679/how-to-read-file-in-java-script-line-by-line-from-hardcoded-path-and-name-of-the)
- [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html/1696884#1696884)
- [Javascript read file without using input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115057/javascript-read-file-without-using-input)

I have, however, seen some references to a Chrome option `--allow-file-access-from-files` which seems to be intended to override this security feature. My javascript is intended for local use only, so it would be totally acceptable for it to only work only in Chrome and only with this option. My problem is I don't know enough about javascript to know how to create a file object for reading, and I can't seem to find documentation on how one would (just assertions that it's forbidden).

**My questions:**

1. Is loading a file based on a hard-coded name 'forbidden' in the sense that one can write the javascript, but a browser won't run it as instructed, or is it 'forbidden' in the sense that the command does not exist in javascript?
2. Given that my project is intended for local use only, and I am therefore able to select any browser/launch flag combination required (e.g. Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`), what is the easiest way to get a javascript file object (suitable for `filereader`) from a hard-coded path? For example, if it can't be done in pure javascript, can I put something in my html which hooks in to the javascript?

Comment: Don't do this. Just don't. If this is only for your own local use, use nodejs or something. Don't run a browser that lets pages modify your filesystem.

Comment: I am working with javascript for the first time because I found an existing project which does almost exactly what I want. I don't really know what it means to use nodejs, but I would be open to it if there's a way that doesn't involve reinventing the wheel (i.e. re-writing the existing project)

Answer (score 0):

For your case, consider using [Tauri](https://tauri.studio/en/). Tauri is a tool to build a web app to a executable desktop app. And Tauri provides [APIs to access local file system](https://tauri.studio/en/docs/api/js/modules/fs).

You could read a binary file from a fixed path like this:

```js
import { readBinaryFile } from '@tauri-apps/api/fs';

async() => {
  data = await readBinaryFile("/path/file");
}
```

Tauri is a lightweight alternative to Electron. For a typical case, one can integrate Tauri in an existing project in one day.